# appending a string to another string

Tags: python

I have 2 lists :

list1 contains "T" "F" "T" "T"

list2 contains "a" "b" "c" "d"

I want to create a third list such that I append element1 in list1 to element1 in list2.

So list3 would be the following: "Ta" "Fb" "Tc" "Td"

How can i do that?

Comment: We all wait in suspense for the next problem from @hssss' homework set.

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip`: `[x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]`.

Answer (score 1):

`zip`, as others have suggested, is good. [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), I would suggest, is better for longer lists.

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> list3 = [x+y for x,y in izip(list1, list2)]
>>> list3
['Ta', 'Fb', 'Tc', 'Td']
```

See also the documentation on [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), they're an essential tool in Python programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your lists

```
>>> t = ["T", "F", "T", "T"]
>>> t1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Group them using zip function:

```
>>> t2 = zip(t, t1)
>>> t2
[('T', 'a'), ('F', 'b'), ('T', 'c'), ('T', 'd')]
```

You could now manipulate the list for desired result:

```
>>> ["".join(x) for x in t2]
['Ta', 'Fb', 'Tc', 'Td']
>>>
```

Comment: Perhaps having two `t`s isn't the best way to demonstrate this functionality.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Yes I agree that can be confusing.